# check if value in data from firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when i'm run my func and get three values (title,id,date)
i'm need to check if title already in my array (nameArr )that resive for my DB

but its dont work , the data end up in my DB twice or three time

my code :

```
const subscribe = async (title, id, date) => {
    const movieRef = db.collection("Members")
    const snapshot = await movieRef.get()
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        if (doc.data().id == sessionStorage["id"]) {
            let nameArr = [...doc.data().subscribe_movie_name]
            if (nameArr.forEach(x => x.title == title)) 
            {
                console.log("pass")
            }
            else {
                nameArr.push({ title: title, id: id, date: date })
                db.collection('Members').doc(doc.id).update(
                    {
                        subscribe_movie_name: nameArr
                    })
                setCountSub(countSub + 1)
            }

        }

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be coming from this line: `if (nameArr.forEach(x => x.title == title))`

The "if" statement is not evaluating `x.title == title` as the condition, which I think is what you want.

To fix this, you can nest the if statement inside the forEach loop and add a boolean variable to determine whether the title should be added to the DB.

```
let addToDB = true
nameArr.forEach(x => {
  if (x.title == title) {
    // if title exists in nameArr, set addToDB to 'false'
    addToDB = false
  }
}
if (addToDB) {
    // add data to DB
}
```

---

Edit to add: You could also replace `.forEach` with `.some` and keep the rest of your existing code the same. (See the ['.some' docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).)